# How to debug iOS6 based application on iOS7 device/simulator?

Tags: ios6, ios7, xcode5, xcode4.6

We are developing an application which was targeted till iOS 6.1 support. Now as iOS 7 has been launched, Apple says it will allow backward compatability for that. Hence iOS 6.1 app should run fine on iOS7 device as well.

While building an app with iOS6.1 targeted devices, it works over iOS7 and UI also appears same like iOS6 (as expected). But there are some crashes over iOS7 devices only, which are not there in iOS6 devices.

I have XCode4.5 and XCode5 both, also we have iOS 6.1 device but not the iOS7 one.

Now how can I check where and why crashes are happening over iOS7 devices, is there anyway to check the same over simulator or is there any specific APIs which makes crashes over iOS7?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it in the simulator, but if you have an Device with iOS 7 you can open xCode 5 and connect the device. Now (re)open xCode 4.5 and the device is shown in the target.

You'll get the crashes in the 'debug area'.
It's always a good idea to test the app on an actual device, not just the simulator.

If you don't want to upgrade to iOS 7, maybe you can get an other device with iOS 7 installed and get the crash logs and symbolicate them.

Ps. i've got multiple test devices running several versions of iOS.